# VBA Timer - subtract time waiting for user input

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this method found on thespreadsheetguru.com to calculate the time it takes to run a macro:

```
Sub CalculateRunTime_Minutes()
'PURPOSE: Determine how many minutes it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

'*****************************
'Insert Your Code Here...
'*****************************

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

It works perfectly for me, but in my code, there are multiple prompts for user input. Some are just OK Buttons, and others are userforms with multiple buttons.

How can I calculate the time it takes to run the macro, minus the time spent waiting on the user to click a button?

Comment: *multiple prompts for user input* - get rid of those prompts and collect user input up front, like create a splash sheet with manual cell entry for user input. If input is needed mid code, create multiple splash points and end code before each splash page and track time that way. -> My comment takes a bit of a turn bc I feel multiple user prompts during code is bad user experience design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code something like this:

```
Sub CalculateRunTime_Minutes()
Dim StartTime1 As Double, StartTime2 As Double, StartTime3 As Double
Dim StopTime1 As Double, StopTime2 As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

StartTime1 = Timer
'your code
StopTime1 = Timer
'user input1

StartTime2 = Timer
'your code
StopTime2 = Timer
'user input2

StartTime3 = Timer
'your code
MinutesElapsed = Format(((Timer - StartTime3) + (StopTime2 - StartTime2) + (StopTime1 - StartTime1)) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking about trying something like this, but I hoped there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Can you implement some kind of PauseTime check?

my VBA is far away but...

```
Dim arrayPausetime() as double
Dim formStartTime as double
Dim formStopTime as double.
```

Everytime you launch your forms requiring user inputs, you take timestamp formStartTime, same when you get out of that form...  formStopTime.

add (formStopTime - formStartTime) into your arrayPausetime and at the end of your macro :

```
dim finalTime as double

for each (double pausetime in arrayPausetime) 
     finalTime  = finalTime  + (Timer - StartTime) - pausetime
```

Hope it helps the brainstorm! :)